# Xmapp + Apache is returning Object not found whenever try to access any page inside htdocs

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache

yesterday that I was working in a php project using xampp, everything was working fine, until I tried previewing a page that I newly modified, then I started getting the following error.

```
Object not found!

    The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

    If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
```

Now I don't know why this error suddenly started appearing or what changed, I have even uninstalled the xampp I was using and installed a more recent and updated one yet to no avail, as the error is still occurring. Here is the current output of my apache error file.

```
[Mon Feb 08 09:37:40.734383 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 264:tid 264] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Feb 08 09:37:41.169408 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 264:tid 264] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Feb 08 09:37:41.376420 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 264:tid 264] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 08 09:37:41.377420 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 264:tid 264] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 10:17:39
[Mon Feb 08 09:37:41.377420 2016] [core:notice] [pid 264:tid 264] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Feb 08 09:37:41.381420 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 264:tid 264] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6236
[Mon Feb 08 09:37:44.429594 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 6236:tid 276] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Feb 08 09:37:44.900621 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 6236:tid 276] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Feb 08 09:37:45.071631 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6236:tid 276] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

I have nothing in my **php_error_file**, any help will be seriously appreciated as I want to upload the site today.

Note: I am working on **Phpstrom v9** in Windows 7. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What kind of url are you trying to access? And is `mod_rewrite` (if needed) on the apache turned on?

Comment: In addition to @Soundz request, can you add the access log? Obviously don't need the whole thing, just the bit relating to the one request you're making. This will help us see if rewrites (if any) are being followed or if there is a difference between the way apache is reading things and what it expects. The vhost itself would also provide information on configuration that might be a bit off (Apache can be a tricky beast).